# Duda sobre GridLayout y Boton

Tags: java, botón, layout, grid, java-awt

Hola necesito hacer un ejercicio para clase en el cual tengo que poner un GridLayout de 8 x 8 en en una casilla aleatoria colocar un boton que ponga atrapame , en los 63 espacios restantes tiene que haber un Label vacio. Se que hay que usar la clase Random para ello pero lo que no se es como poner en una casilla especifica el boton , ayuda porfavor. Por ahora esto es lo que tengo de codigo

```
public Atrapa_al_boton(){
    Panel pPrincipal = new Panel(new GridLayout(8 , 8));
    this.add(pPrincipal);
    setTitle("Atrapa al boton");
    setSize(400 , 400);
    setVisible(true);
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 63; i++) {
        Label label = new Label("");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Comprendo tu duda; puedo sugerirte primero asignarle el valor `Random` a la 'posición' que tendrá el boton y luego dentro del ciclo validar ese numero frente a `i`, cuando sean iguales se crea el `JButton` en dicha posición aleatoria, quiero decir:

```
public Atrapa_al_boton(){
  Panel pPrincipal = new Panel(new GridLayout(8 , 8));
  this.add(pPrincipal);
  setTitle("Atrapa al boton");
  setSize(400 , 400);
  setVisible(true);
  Random r = new Random();
  int bPos = r.nextInt(64);//posicion para el JButton
  JComponent C;

  for(int i=0;i<64;i++) {
    if(i==bPos)
      C=new JButton("B");
    else
      C=new JLabel("L");
    pPrincipal.add(C);
  }

  /*for (int i = 0; i <= 63; i++) {
    Label label = new Label("");
  }*/
}
```